# Bayesian Network with R

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I am trying to build a Bayesian network model. However I am unable to install a suitable package. Tried `gRain`, `bnlearn` and `Rgraphviz` for plotting. I have tried in R 2.15 and 3.2

Following are the error messages :

```
library(gRain)
Loading required package: gRbase
Loading required package: graph
Error: package ‘graph’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called ‘graph’

> install.packages("graph")
Warning message:
package ‘graph’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)
```

Same for R 3.2.1

```
> install.packages("graph")
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘graph’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1) 


> install.packages("Rgraphviz")
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") : unable to resolve 'cran.r-project.org'
2: package ‘Rgraphviz’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

> install.packages("Rgraphviz")
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘Rgraphviz’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)
```

### Other info for the model

1) No of variables - 17
2) Type of variables - discrete/continuous

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The packages`graph`, `RBGL` and `Rgraphviz` are not on CRAN but on [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/).

To install these packages, execute

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(c("graph", "RBGL", "Rgraphviz"))
```

Then install the packages from CRAN in the usual way:

```
install.packages("gRain", dependencies=TRUE)
```

See also the [`gRain` installation instructions](http://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/software/gR/).

Comment: You may need to use the `force=T` argument to `BiocManager::install` if some of the packages have the same or higher versions, otherwise they won't be installed.

Answer (score 4):

For R version 3.5 or greater, you can install *Bioconductor* packages using *BiocManager*.
Please see: https://bioconductor.org/install.
I installed them using the following code:

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.10")
BiocManager::install(c("gRbase", "RBGL", "Rgraphviz", "gRain"))
```