# R studio malfunction + Error in .requirePackage(package) after package installation

Tags: r, installation, package, rstudio

My RStudio is not working after trying to install `gRain` the way as suggested by this post [Bayesian Network with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252102/bayesian-network-with-r). It is now unable to load some required packages such as `party`. Also, I noticed some weird gaps in the data display (attached a screen shot). I can't reinstall RStudio as I got some important job data on it. Can anyone tell me what is happening with my R?

[image: Rstudio malfunction]

Comment: "I can't reinstall RStudio as I got some important job data on it" - generally data is not stored **in** RStudio, it's stored in `.Rdata` files that won't be affected by a reinstall. But you're right to be cautious about losing data, and you know your data better than we do.

Comment: Thank Marius, so if I reinstall R studio, how to bring all of my job data back to the list?

Comment: You should be writing your script to a file, which you can rerun at any time, reproducing your steps on demand. You need to realize that RStudio is just a shell around R made to make interaction with R a bit smoother.